# Using python handles on cuda allocated memory with ctypes

Tags: python, c, cuda, ctypes, void-pointers

I'm trying to use python to control cuda, through ctypes.  Here, to illustrate my problem, I use python to pass pointers along to c functions which allocate cuda memory, copy numpy array to cuda mempory, and copy cuda memory back to a new numpy array. But it doesnt seem to work, despite my basic ctypes setup working.  I think the issue is with what's being returned from cudaMalloc function to python.

here's the python code

```
  pycu_alloc = dll.alloc_gpu_mem
  pycu_alloc.argtypes = [c_size_t]
  pycu_alloc.restypes = [c_void_p]   

  host2gpu = dll.host2gpu
  host2gpu.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_size_t]

  gpu2host = dll.gpu2host
  gpu2host.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_void_p, c_size_t]

  a = np.random.randn(1024).astype('float32')
  c = np.zeros(1024).astype('float32')

  c_a = c_void_p(a.ctypes.data)
  c_c = c_void_p(c.ctypes.data)

  da = pycu_alloc(1024)
  c_da = c_void_p(da)

  host2gpu(c_a, c_da, 1024)
  gpu2host(c_c, c_da, 1024)

  print a
  print c
```

and the C:

```
extern "C" {
float *  alloc_gpu_mem( size_t N)
{
  float *d;
  int size = N *sizeof(float);
  int err;

  err = cudaMalloc(&d, size);

  printf("cuda malloc: %d\n", err);
  return d;
 }}

 extern "C" {
 void host2gpu(float * a, void * da, size_t N)
 {
  int size = N * sizeof(float);
  int err;
  err = cudaMemcpy(da, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  printf("load mem: %d\n", err);
  }}

  extern "C"{
 void gpu2host(float *c, void *d_c, size_t N)
 {
  int  err;
  int size = N*sizeof(float);
  err = cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("cpy mem back %d\n", err);
 }}
```

The code should copy a random vector `a` to cuda memory, and then copy that cuda memory back to an empty vector `c`.  When I print `c`, thought, it is just `0`s.

I've wrestled with different possibilities of the `float*` and `void*`, particularly in the way `alloc_gpu_mem` works.  But I don't know what to do.

As for the `err` return values, the `cudaMalloc` returns `0` but both `cudaMemcpy` return 11.

What's python doing wrong with the pointer? Help?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but… have you tried the existing Python CUDA bindings from [Andreas Klöckner](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda/) (which I think are the same ones Nvidia links to from their website, but I haven't checked)?

Comment: No I was looking at that and I probably should have used them but I wanted to dive in and control the cuda myself to make sure I knew what was going on.  then i got caught up giving myself python handles because it would be really nice for me.  but alas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
pycu_alloc.restypes = [c_void_p]
```

This doesn't do anything. What you wanted was:

```
pycu_alloc.restype = c_void_p
```

See [Return types](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types) in the `ctypes` docs.

And without that, `ctypes` assumes that your function returns a C `int`. On a 32-bit platform, you might get away with it, because you end up constructing a `c_void_p` whose value is that `int`… but on a 64-bit platform, that pointer is going to end up with the upper 32 bits missing.

So, when you pass that into CUDA, it recognizes that the pointer isn't in any range it knows about, and gives you back a `cudaErrorInvalidValue` (11).

Also, if you get everything right, this line should be unnecessary:

```
c_da = c_void_p(da)
```

You're calling a function whose `argtypes` specifies `c_void_p`, so you can pass it an `int` that you got from a `c_void_p`-returning function just fine.

---

You can see the same behavior with plain old `malloc` and `free`, except that you'll probably get a segfault at `free` instead of a nice error:

```
malloc = libc.malloc
malloc.argtypes = [c_size_t]
malloc.restype = c_void_p # comment this line to crash on most 64-bit platforms

free = libc.free
free.argtypes = [c_void_p]
free.restype = None

a = malloc(1024)
free(a) # commenting this line and uncommenting the next two has no effect
#c_a = c_void_p(a)
#free(ca)
```

Comment: @Ethan: Remember to be careful with types that have data descriptors yet still give a `__dict__` to instances. ctypes data types allow this because they're designed to be subclassed to support additional state and interfaces. Unfortunately it's easy to mistakenly create a new attribute like `restypes`. If you tried to assign `[c_void_p]` to the correct `restype` attribute you would at least get a `TypeError`. The REPL, `dir` and `help` are your friends.